# PHP Regex: How to get capital words then add string if a ucwords matches?

Tags: php, regex

I have this dynamic string

> "ZAN ROAD HOG HEADWRAPS The most
>   popular ZAN headwrap style-features
>   custom and original artwork"

**EDIT**
How can I check all the capital words then if I encountered a ucwords() or title case word then I will automatically add a '--' after the last capital word?
Note: The capital words are the product name and the first ucwords() or title case word is the start of the product description.

I have this code right now but its not working at the moment:

```
<?php 
$str = preg_replace( '/\s+/', ' ', $sentence );
$words = array_reverse( explode( ' ', $str ) );
foreach ( $words as $k => $s ) {
    if ( preg_match( '/\b[A-Z]{5,}\b/', $s ) ) {
        $words[$k] = $s . " --";
        break;
    }
}
$short_desc = addslashes( trim( join( ' ', array_reverse( $words ) ) )); 
?>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So something like "ZAN ROAD HOG HEADWRAPS -- The..."?

Comment: Yes. The example sentence can also be "ZAN ROAD The most" and the result will be "ZAN ROAD -- The most". Thanks :)

Comment: Many problems solved not in one manner, but many other points of view exists. If you define your problem, we'll more precisely approach. Perhaps using any skill we have

Comment: Up. This problem is still not solved. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this:

```
$str = preg_replace('/^(?:\p{Lu}+\s+)+(?=\p{Lu}*\p{Ll})/u', '$0-- ', $str);
```

Here `^(?:\p{Lu}+\s+)+` describes a sequence of words at the begin of the string that are separated by whitespace where each word is a sequence of uppercase letters (`\p{Lu}`, see [Unicode character properties](http://php.net/regexp.reference.unicode)). The look-ahead assertion `(?=\p{Lu}*\p{Ll})` is just to ensure that there actually is something following that contains a lowercase letter.

Comment: Need a single whitespace after `--`

Comment: Nice a regex god :D Cool I will try it now. Thanks for the fast reply sir! :)

Comment: Update: I think it misses some other sentence but I think it is close.

Answer (score 0):

You can just look for capital letters in the start of the string:

```
$regexp = "/^([A-Z][A-Z\s]+)([A-Z].+)/";
$matches = $preg_match($regexp, $string);
$out = $matches[1] . "-- " . $matches[2];
```

The first [A-Z] looks for a capital letter in the beginning of the line
The next [A-Z\s]+ looks for 1 or more capital letters or spaces
Then, [A-Z].+ looks for the first capital letter of the remaining text and any character subsequently.

The remaining lines are, I hope, self explanatory

-Pranav

Answer (score 0):

By performing a non-global replacement (informing `preg_replace()` that you only wish to make one replacement), you can avoid using `^` to anchor your pattern to the front of the input string.

The targeted position of your insert string immediately follows that final occurrence of "one or more uppercase letters followed by a space".

No capture groups or references are needed.  `\K` in the pattern says "restart the fullstring match" in other words "release/forget any previously matched characters and start matching from this point".  ...then we just don't match anymore characters -- this delivers the zero-length position to insert the `--`.  Effectively, no characters are lost in the action.

Code: ([PHP Demo](https://3v4l.org/e8BmE)) ([Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/nkMscs/1))

```
$string = "ZAN ROAD HOG HEADWRAPS The most popular ZAN headwrap style-features custom and original artwork";
echo preg_replace('~(?:[A-Z]+ )+\K~', '-- ', $string, 1);

echo "\n---\n";

echo preg_replace('~^(?:[A-Z]+ )+\K~', '-- ', $string);  // without telling function to perform a single replacement
```

Output:

```
ZAN ROAD HOG HEADWRAPS -- The most popular ZAN headwrap style-features custom and original artwork
---
ZAN ROAD HOG HEADWRAPS -- The most popular ZAN headwrap style-features custom and original artwork
```

---

As a fringe case acknowledgement, if you have a product description that starts with `A` or `I`, then the pattern will need to be fortified slightly to accommodate.  This could be achieved a number of ways; this seems simple/logical/direct to me: ([Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/nkMscs/2))

```
~(?:[A-Z]+ )+\K(?=[A-Z])~
```